# eclipse Helios, J2EE perspective, file & folder name shown as null

Tags: eclipse

Hello everyone on stackoverflow,

I've tried to test out the new and latest version of eclipse, Helio. After the installation, i  install a nightly build of SpringSource toolsuite by following their instruction.

after the update, every works fine. but when i load my existing project from SVN, on the "Project Explorer" view, all file and folder other than the java source category, their name are shown as null.

This problem only happens when i work within the J2EE perspective. when i switch to other perspective, i don't see such problem.

Anyone here has any idea about this?

Thanks,

Comment: This problem only happen in project explorer. so it happens in all perspective. i confuse between project explorer and package explorer that's why i said earlier than the error only happen in J2EE perspective and not the other.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I disconnect a project from SVN, it will display the correct name again. So it might be related to Subclipse.